# Convert a piecewise function to Heaviside function

Tags: calculus

In the class, I have seen two examples for converting a piecewise function into a Heaviside function, however the piecewise function in those example is only defined on [0,∞), so what about the domain is the entire real line.

For example the function :

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}y = x+2, x \in [-1, 0]\\ y = 2-x, x \in (0,1]\\y = 1, \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So, how could I convert this function into Heaviside function?

Comment: Please use Mathjax (latex) to format your equations. Check if my changes are correct. Also notice that you have discontinuities. Are you sure you got the intervals/ sign correct? Is this supposed to look like a peak? Then in the first case $y=x+2$, and in the second case $y=2-x$.

Comment: @Andrei yes you are right, I correct the function, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have :
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}y = g(x), x \in [a, b]\\ y = h(x), x \in (b,c]\\ y=k,\;\;\;\; \text{elsewhere}\;\text{(i.e. $x<a\;\mbox{and}\;x>c$)}\end{cases}
$$

Then $f(x)$ can be written as :
$$
f(x)=g(x)[H(x-a)-H(x-b)]+h(x)[H(x-b)-H(x-c)]+k[H(x-c)-H(x-a)]
$$

Comment: How about the third request, $1$ elsewhere?

Comment: For the third request it is same as saying $y=1$ for $x>c$ and so the third one is written as the following : $1(H(x-c))$

Comment: Or for $x < a$ ...

Comment: Here you assume the signal starts exactly at $x=a$

Comment: The OP did not assume that. Anyway, add it and make the answer complete!